Compatibility of TRANSFORM library with OpenModelica
I wanted to know if TRANSFORM library is now compatible with OpenModelica ? And if yes, the degree of compatibility with OpenModelica. I'm running the test on this config:
OS : Windows 10 22H2
TRANSFORM: version 0.4
OPENMODELICA: v1.22.3-64bit
When I try to run PumpingSytem example from fluid package of the TRANSFORM library which is the same model than the one in the MSL but with TRANSFORM components I got these errors:
[1] 14:06:23 Translation Notification

[TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialDistributedVolume: 12:26-12:31]: From here:

[2] 14:06:23 Translation Error
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialDistributedVolume: 12:3-13:40]: Non-array modification '0' for array component 'min', possibly due to missing 'each'.

[3] 14:06:23 Translation Notification

[TRANSFORM.Fluid.ClosureRelations.Geometry.Models.DistributedVolume_1D.GenericPipe: 27:29-27:62]: From here:

[4] 14:06:23 Translation Error
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.ClosureRelations.Geometry.Models.DistributedVolume_1D.GenericPipe: 27:3-28:50]: Non-array modification '(-Modelica.Constants.pi / 2.0) - 0.01' for array component 'min', possibly due to missing 'each'.

[5] 14:06:23 Translation Notification

[TRANSFORM.Fluid.ClosureRelations.Geometry.Models.DistributedVolume_1D.GenericPipe: 27:63-27:95]: From here:

[6] 14:06:23 Translation Error
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.ClosureRelations.Geometry.Models.DistributedVolume_1D.GenericPipe: 27:3-28:50]: Non-array modification 'Modelica.Constants.pi / 2.0 + 0.01' for array component 'max', possibly due to missing 'each'.

[7] 14:06:23 Translation Notification

[TRANSFORM.Fluid.Volumes.BaseClasses.PartialVolume: 78:36-78:66]: From here:

[8] 14:06:23 Translation Error
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.Volumes.BaseClasses.PartialVolume: 78:3-79:42]: Non-array modification 'StateSelect.prefer' for array component 'stateSelect', possibly due to missing 'each'.

[1] 14:07:26 Translation Notification

[TRANSFORM.Fluid.ClosureRelations.Geometry.Models.DistributedVolume_1D.GenericPipe: 27:29-27:62]: From here:

[2] 14:07:26 Translation Error
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.ClosureRelations.Geometry.Models.DistributedVolume_1D.GenericPipe: 27:3-28:50]: Non-array modification '(-Modelica.Constants.pi / 2.0) - 0.01' for array component 'min', possibly due to missing 'each'.
 


FYI: I can confirm that the model passes a pedantic check and simulates without warnings in Dymola

@ReneJustNielsen, unfortunately Dymola doesn't detect scalar array modifiers which are missing the "each" modifier but according to the specification they need to be present.

I made a PR (pull request):
https://github.com/ORNL-Modelica/TRANSFORM-Library/pull/101
with the needed changes to the TRANSFORM library:

to make the models according to the Modelica specification:
https://specification.modelica.org/master/inheritance-modification-and-redeclaration.html#S2.I2.i1.p1
to be able to simulate them with OpenModelica (hopefully, I haven't checked that, just ran Check Model on them)

Probably some other examples from the library have the same issue but I haven't looked into any other sublibraries than Fluid.
